# Atomic file creation and lock

Tags: java, file, locking, atomic

I need a thread-safe method to atomically create a new file and immediately lock it.

The method `FileChannel.open()`, with the `StandardOpenOption` `CREATE_NEW` and `WRITE`, does the creation part atomically. However the `lock()` method wouldn't be called in the same "transaction".

For instance, if

```
FileChannel.open(Paths.get("log.txt"),StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW,
    StandardOpenOption.WRITE).lock()
```

and

```
new FileWriter("log.txt").write("Hello world")
```

are executed simultaneously, it could happen that the file `log.txt` is created via `open()`, but the lock is acquired only after the write operation.
I need `open()` to throw an exception in this situation, so that I can handle it (for instance, adding a counter to the filename).

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For now, I would `truncate()` the `FileChannel` after the lock, but this sounds too much punishing for writers that don't lock their files.